# How to associate languages with files without extensions in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to edit a Gemfile in Notepad++, but since Gemfiles don't have extensions, there doesn't seem to be a way to make Notepad++ automatically detect Gemfile as a Ruby file. I have to manually set the language every time I open a Gemfile.

Is there a way to have Notepad++ recognize the language of a file based on its full name, not just its extension? Is there a plugin for this? Thanks.

Comment: Not without a plugin, I'm afraid...

Comment: @BoltClock I'm fine with a plugin. Do you know of one that supports this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BoltClock said, not without a plugin. I'll mark this as the answer until someone else provides a better one.

Comment: Do You know the name of the plugin ?

Comment: @Marty I asked the same thing myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786906/how-to-associate-languages-with-files-without-extensions-in-notepad/12097815#comment15658682_11786906

Answer (score 2):

I found a plugin which can detect the language based on vi modelines and shebangs et:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonplugsq/files/Modeline%20Parser/

You need to install the Python Script plugin from the plugin manager, and manually install ModelineParser_0.2.zip If needed it may be possible to add your own custom recognition strings.

Comment: The current version of Modeline Parser, v0.2, is (c) 2011, and doesn't appear to work with NotePad++ v6.8.6. If anyone knows of an update/replacement/fix, please let us know!