# Add a file extension to COMMIT_EDITMSG

Tags: git, notepad++

git version 2.10.2.windows.1

I use notepad++ as my commit editor for git. I would like to open the editor using the Diff language when running `git commit -v` so I can browse my diffs more easily (Diff highlights + / - lines differently). The file git opens to edit is named `COMMIT_EDITMSG` (no extension). Notepad++ cannot natively associate an extension-less file with a language (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11786906/2602982)).

How can I configure git to change the file it opens for editing commits? The [git commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt-codeGITDIRCOMMITEDITMSGcode) docs refer to this file but only describe its purpose:

> $GIT_DIR/COMMIT_EDITMSG
>
> This file contains the commit message of a commit in progress. If git commit exits due to an error before creating a commit, any commit message that has been provided by the user (e.g., in an editor session) will be available in this file, but will be overwritten by the next invocation of git commit.

Comment: Maybe the "prepare-commit-message" [hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) and the `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample` hook sample would be useful for you?

Comment: Can notepad++ associate a link file with a language? If it can, maybe you could create a link `commit.diff` to `$GIT_DIR/COMMIT_EDITMSG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't provide a way to change the file name used for commit messages. It's hard-coded in the source and various pieces of the code (not to mention plugins and hooks) depend on these exact names.

Typically editors provide some sort of pattern matching to associate a file type with an arbitrary file name pattern. It sounds like Notepad++ doesn't, so you may need to use a plugin, a different technique, or a different editor for editing commit messages.

Vim, for example, supports "modelines" at the start and end of files to set file-level variables. You could add the following line to force a file to be highlighted using "diff" syntax:

`# vi:syntax=diff`

If you find a functional modeline-style plugin, as mentioned in the other question, you can use the `prepare-commit-message` hook to insert a modeline at the bottom, which will cause the file to be highlighted as you want.